# How to group and select elements of dataframe using tidyr/dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a table in the tibble format which I need to rearrange:

```
AUS   CAN   DEN   original_period

NA    NA    4.3    1955-02
3.2   NA    NA     1955-02
NA    1.1   NA     1955-02
3.1   NA    NA     1955-03
NA    NA    9.7    1955-03
NA    1.2   NA     1955-03
```

So as of now I have one valid value per item per row. My aim is to eliminate all the NAs and all the `original_period` duplicates, so that my table looks like this:

```
AUS   CAN   DEN   original_period

3.2   1.1   4.3    1955-02
3.1   1.2   9.7    1955-03
```

Anyone know how to do this efficiently using tidyr or dplyr?

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(h=T,strin=F,text="
AUS   CAN   DEN   original_period
NA    NA    4.3    1955-02
3.2   NA    NA     1955-02
NA    1.1   NA     1955-02
3.1   NA    NA     1955-03
NA    NA    9.7    1955-03
NA    1.2   NA     1955-03")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can group by 'original_period' and with `summarise_all` either remove all the `NA` elements per row with `na.omit` (assuming that the NA elements are distributed equally across groups in all columns) or use `mean/max/min` etc if there is only single non-NA observation per group

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(original_period) %>%
    summarise_all(mean, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
    # or remove the NAs with na.omit
    #summarise_all(na.omit) %>%       
    select(names(df1))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#     AUS   CAN   DEN original_period    
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>          
#1   3.2   1.1   4.3 1955-02        
#2   3.1   1.2   9.7 1955-03
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `coalesce` :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(original_period) %>%
  summarise_all(~coalesce(!!!.))

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   original_period   AUS   CAN   DEN
#   <chr>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 1955-02           3.2   1.1   4.3
# 2 1955-03           3.1   1.2   9.7
```